# What is my secret message?

Tags: cipher, visual, steganography

What's my secret message hidden in my image?

[image]

EDIT: To better my wording, you should save the image. Either through the link below, or by right clicking the image above and using Save Image As.

Direct Download link: [link](https://i.cubeupload.com/oGJmQn.png)

Hint 1:

> Using an image editor won't help.

Hint 2:

> This question's tags could help.

Hint 3:

> Try looking closely at its text - but not the most obvious text.

Hint 4:

> The second stage is the hardest. Unscramble what type of encryption I have used: `sabe xtisy ofru`

Comment: Just a note, the fact that you say you need to 'download' the image made me, and others, instantly suspicious you may be trying to get us to download a virus. However I realised what you were trying to do, and I think it would be better if you just said that you needed to *SAVE* the image, which is all you need to do...

Comment: Oh yeah. Didn't really think about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final answer is

> I HAVE MANY ELEPHANTS BECAUSE MY CARPET IS SO HARD.

Saving the image and then opening it in notepad you get the following message at the bottom:

> WELL DONE! THE ANSWER IS: I HAVE NO ELEPHANTS BECAUSE MY CARPET IS TOO SOFT.
> JUST KIDDING. THAT WOULD BE WAY TOO EASY. TO GET THE ACTUAL ANSWER, WORK OUT THIS ONE: SSBIQVZFIE1BTlkgRUxFUEhBTlRTIEJFQ0FVU0UgTVkgQ0FSUEVUIElTIFNPIEhBUkQu

That is clear

> base sixty four

And says

> I HAVE MANY ELEPHANTS BECAUSE MY CARPET IS SO HARD.

Comment: Why are my puzzles so easy?! Well done :)